# App crashes after returning from safari

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In my app i load a weburl in safari when a button is clicked.

When this is loaded and we go back in the app: when i try to drag an object ( in this case an arrowview, the app crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I really can't find what causes this cause it only happens when dragging ... everything else works just fine.

The app crashes at this piece of code (in the Arrowview class):

```
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{


   self.center = CGPointMake(plateImg.endPoint.x , plateImg.endPoint.y)  ;

   [arrowImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(34, 38)];            **<< CRASHES HERE**



}
```

Anybody know why this is happening ?

Comment: what does the error log say? no hints there? Also, are you using ARC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out after some deep reviewing i simply forgot to retain the arrowImage  ( used Image at url method wich doesn't retain the object